# Write Linux driver for device so that proprietary Windows software can work with it in Wine

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, wine

I have USB oscilloscope [Velleman PCSU 1000](http://www.vellemanusa.com/products/view/?country=us&id=522377&lang=enu) which is Windows-only, and I'm thinking of ways to make it work in Linux.

I've come across interesting [publication on driver reverse-engineering](http://goo.gl/gnhW4D), so, at least in theory, I can reverse-engineer the driver for the oscilloscope, and then write Linux driver for it. But I have no idea how to make their proprietary software work in Wine with my new driver? Is it possible?

If not, then it seems I have only one option: write not only the driver, but reimplement the software as well. This is awful amount of work, unfortunately.

And, as far as I know, there is no common device class for this kind of devices, so I can't write some generic driver to make any other similar software work with the oscilloscope. Right?

Anyway, any suggestions and ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: This is really much too broad for a Q&A site. You need to find a discussion forum where other people are working on similar driver issues and find out where to start.

Comment: I did such trick with usb pen tablet, by tracing usb packets and responses (AFAIK wireshark does that, but I did it in linux with "wrong driver"). But tablet's protocol is simple: x, y, pressure and couple of extra bytes (so I touched all corners and discovered what each number means), don't expect that from oscilloscope.

Comment: @myaut, yes, reverse-engineering of the oscilloscope protocol is a great challenge, and I will probably fail. But, the question is about different thing: assume the protocol is already known. Now what? Is it possible to write Linux driver so that existing proprietary Windows software will work with it in Wine? (well, Z̷͙̗̻͖̣̹͉̫̬̪̖̤͆ͤ̓ͫͭ̀̐͜͞ͅͅαлγo already answered that I'll need customized Wine for that, this is of course not an option)

Comment: Well, I came to this link: https://www.winehq.org/wwn/331#USB%20Support%20in%20Wine . Note that it is much easier to implement usb device support with `libusb` because you're doing everything in userspace. But, it seems not to be integrated with Wine in any way (according to link)